# React component doesn't rerender

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

There is a custom `<Select />` react component, which contains 4 options - 4 alarm levels:

1. Critical
2. Major
3. Minor
4. Warning

The `<Select />` component is getting used multiple times. Each time pressing on the **add new** button, a new `<Select />` gets created.

**The `<Select />` component is supposed to have just a single one of its options active at  the time.** For ex. There can be rendered `<Select />`-s rendered with just 1 critical, 1 major, 1 minor and 1 warning values, never two of the same time.
When pressing the add new button to create a new `<Select />`, it automatically chooses the available option with the smallest index. (see the list above for indexes: 1-4)

**The new `<Select />`s created have the values that the `<Select />`s which were created before them had DISABLED (unclickable)**

**The problem:**

New `<Select />`s work just as planned, ex. 3rd component created, has its first and second options disabled. But the first component **has all of its options available and active**, which is entirely wrong. It was supposed to disable its second and third options.[image: correct image]
**The "not rendered last" components do not rerender on the change of the state. Because they do not pass the Virtual DOM check, react doesn't see a change on DOM, so it doesn't rerender that component.**

*Methods that I've tried:*

1. adding an empty item to the `<Select />` component and changing its id/class with every new `<Select />` added on the page, so that react sees that an id is changed and rerenders it
2. forceUpdate()
3. writing a function that manually changes the state for component's rerender (almost same as forceUpdate())

**How to make the components rendered before the new ones to see changes that they make and rerender?**

Basically the code is the react-enhanced version of this, so didn't consider necessary to add it entirely here.

```
<select>
  <option class="1" value="Critical">critical</option>
  <option class="2" value="Minor">major</option>
  <option class="3" value="Minor">minor</option>
  <option class="4" value="Warning">warning</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use setState on select change because of setState always call render function. I'm just guessing because you didn't paste the code.

Comment: Every time that I mentioned “changing state” in the question, it was meant changing by setState :)

Comment: post your code!

Comment: The ***react-enhanced version of this*** is what we need to see, since that is where the logic of what you are trying to do resides.. Even better if you could **also** provide a working [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: Add your entire React code. It will make it easy to figure out where the exact problem is.